# Powershell ConvertTo-SecureString ObjectNotFound

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

After upgrading to powershell 3.0 existing scripts stopped working with an error

```
ConvertTo-SecureString : The term 'ConvertTo-SecureString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ConvertTo-SecureString
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ConvertTo-SecureString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I found that ConvertTo-SecureString is [supported](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849818%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) on PS 3.0. Do I need to include it somehow?

Comment: Did *all* scripts stop working? Or only scripts with `ContertTo-SecureString` in them?

Comment: On my 3.0 the corresponding DLL is located here `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.dll`.  You might check to see if that dll is at that path.  You should also have this directory: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security`

Comment: BTW which OS are you on?  Do you have any server products installed like Exchange, SharePoint Server, SCCM, etc?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Import-Module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security'
```

fixes the issue. I don't know why this module is not loaded by default.

Comment: That import executed without displaying an error, but did not fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The following does NOT work.

```
C:\contoso>powershell -command {$secured='random text'|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;$secured;}

'ConvertTo-SecureString' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\contoso>
```

---

The following does work.

```
C:\contoso>copy con: tfile1.ps1
$secured='random text'|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;
$secured;
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\contoso>powershell -file tfile1.ps1
System.Security.SecureString

C:\contoso>
```

This also works.

```
C:\contoso>powershell "& {$secured='random text'|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;$secured}"
System.Security.SecureString

C:\contoso>
```

---

I'll leave why it doesn't work as a -command to someone else as I'm only a powershell novice.

S.

Comment: Your answer is not related to the problem above, but I came here because I think I had the same problem as you (calling PS with `ConvertTo-SecureString` from cmd or PS). Your workaround is not based on the fact, that you use additional variables, but on the fact that you invoke the command a layer deeper. Just to clarify, this will also work: `powershell "& {ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText 'random text' -Force}"`